# Create an AngularJS promise with no return value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am using `$q` to wrap a promise around a legacy callback. However, the existing callback doesn't have a value to return. It takes a success function with no parameters.

```
angular.module('MyModule').service('MyService', function() {
    function initialize() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        LegacyFactory.initialize(
            // 'void' Success Callback
            function () {
                deferred.resolve (/* WHAT DO I PUT HERE? */);
            },
            // Error Callback
            function (errorCode) {
                deferred.reject(errorCode);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
});
```

I can't find a `void` version of `resolve` in the AngularJS docs. I can return a dummy value, but then clients might access that dummy value, which would cause confusion.

How do I create an AngularJS promise with no return value?

NOTE: The question [AngularJS promise returning empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261872) is completely different. That question does return a value in the `resolve` function.

Comment: Just resolve with nothing.. `deferred.resolve()`?

Comment: @PSL Is that possible? The docs don't mention it.

Comment: Yes you can resolve with no value. Just give it a try and see what happens.. :) http://plnkr.co/edit/BpYqlg?p=preview

Comment: I use `deferred.resolve()` all the time.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini yes, but is this undocumented behavior which may change? Is there a doc somewhere mentioning this behavior?

Comment: seriously people. Don't downvote this question. It's a perfectly valid question for someone who's new to JavaScript but coming from a typed language.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no `void` data type in JavaScript. Instead JavaScript uses the primitive type `undefined` that is used to represent a variable that has not been assigned a value.

A method or statement that has no return value will return `undefined`. A function that doesn't use the `return` statement will return `undefined`. An argument that isn't passed to a function will be `undefined`.

I hope you're starting to see the consistent behavior here of `undefined`.

```
function foo(x) { console.log(x); }
foo(); // will print undefined
function zoom() {}
console.log(zoom()); // will print undefined
```

So when you use `deferred.resolve()` you are passing `undefined` as the value for the data argument.

To more specifically answer your question.

**"How do I create an AngularJS promise with no return value?"**

To write JavaScript code that gives the intent of no return value for the promise. You would write this.

```
deferred.resolve(undefined);
```

That makes it clear that there is no intended data.

Later in your callback you don't have to define the data argument, but if you want you can.

```
 foo().then(function(data){
     if(typeof data === 'undefined') {
          // there is no data
     } else {
          // there is data
     });
```

if you **always** expect no data, then just do this.

```
foo().then(function(){
   // handle success
});
```

Comment: Nice, detailed answer! I was under the impression that the false-y behavior of `undefined` would mess with the internal comparison algorithm of the `promise` :)

Comment: @metacubed true, but Angulars promise code doesn't touch the data value being passed to the callback. Here in the source code you can see that `value` is just passed as is. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L447